# Which statistical test should be used?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, spss, nonparametric, manova

I am stuck in deciding which statistical test would be more appropriate in my case. My research questions are whether or not in the gait analysis there are differences in pressure between ten foot zones and two defined groups with respect to time (three instants: First peak, valley, second peak).
So my dataset is divided in 5 columns (IDs, Group, Foot_zones, 1st peak, valley, 2nd peak) with lots of rows (160). The 3 dependent variables are not normally distributed *(p < 0.05)*. Which test should I use?

Precisely,
the objective of my study is to prove that there are differences between plantar pressure between healthy subjects and diabetic patients mapping the plantar surface in 10 regions of interest. The pressure is measured at 3 defined instants : 1st peak, valley and 2nd peak which are the plot distribution of the vertical resultants of the ground reaction forces. As for this, check the sample dataset here provided --> [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yIEdFviUCul033o7LXEyIRKCF0_yqHNe) Where you can see 5 subjects for the diabetic group (n° 0) and 11 for the healthy group (n°11).

I was thinking about

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to this site. Please indicate your objective of study  Also show a sample (part) of your data in rows and columns etc.

Comment: Why would you test whether the marginal distribution of the dependent variables is normal?

Comment: Because with a  Friedman test, which is non-parametric  I cannot insert any factor group so that I can only account for possible statistical differences in the 3 dependent variables. Which it doesn't tell me anything important...